# how to get all the contents of "alt"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to **scrape** a text html
here is my html text that i'm trying to scrape,  especially what i'm looking for to recover are the attributes or contained in 'alt'?

```
html_text = """
<td class="kx max" onclick="e_t.track_click('lo-button-click', 'block-1x2_ft_2');"><span class=" number-wrap  down" alt="4.10[d]3.80" eu="4.10[d]3.80">3.80</span></td>
"""
```

this is what i did

```
print(soup.find_all('span','alt'))
```

I expect the output to be `"4.10 [d] 3.80"`

Comment: always worth mentioning what the actual result of your code is as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tag['alt']` value

```
print(soup.select_one('.number-wrap.down')['alt'])
```

---

To get multiple items.

```
for item in soup.select('.number-wrap.down'):
    print(item['alt'])
```

---

```
import bs4
html_text = """
<td class="kx max" onclick="e_t.track_click('lo-button-click', 'block-1x2_ft_2');"><span class=" number-wrap  down" alt="4.10[d]3.80" eu="4.10[d]3.80">3.80</span></td>
<td class="kx max" onclick="e_t.track_click('lo-button-click', 'block-1x2_ft_2');">
<span class=" number-wrap  down" alt="4.10[d]3.80" eu="4.10[d]3.80">3.80</span></td>
"""
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_text,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.number-wrap.down'):
    print(item['alt'])
```